# How to copy folder contents recursively in gradle zipTree?

Tags: file, build, gradle, war

```
copy {
   from zipTree(rootDir.getPath() + "/archive.war")
   include 'dirAbc/subdir/'

   into 'src/dirEfg/subdir/'
   includeEmptyDirs = false
}
```

I am trying to copy a folder and its contents (including subfolders and their contents), from a war file to a local location.

I have almost got what I want. The problem is the above leaves me with the following directory structure:

*src/dirEfg/subdir/dirAbc/subdir/*

instead of what I want and was expecting:

*src/dirEfg/subdir/*

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe just change from `into 'src/dir/subdir/'` to `into 'src/'`?

Comment: That is not a runner, I've changed my directory names to avoid confusion that I caused.. sorry about that.

Comment: I basically just want a specific subfolder in the war file, and all it's recursive contents. I do not want any of the parent folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is currently not possible out of the box with the current implementation of `zipTree` in Gradle.

This enhancement is tracked in [this ticket](https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-3025).

There are some workarounds you can try as suggested in [this post](http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/ziptree_expand_only_given_subdirectory) in the Gradle forums.
One of them hints at extracting the zip tree and moving/renaming the contents.

Comment: I've used a temp directory to simulate this behaviour in a sub task.